# Number of combinations when splitting people into 2 groups different size groups and two specific people can't be on the same team.

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

So there is this problem in my textbook that asks: 
"We have **12 people** that we want to split into **two teams of 5 and 7 respectively**. In how many ways can we do that, if **two specific people can't be in the same team**?"

My way of tackling it was finding out in how many ways we can split the remaining 10 people into two teams of 4 and 6 respectively and then multiplying that by 2 (since one person can be on "Team of 7" and the other on "Team of 5" but also vice versa).
So **C(10, 6)*2 = 420**.

But the solution given by the textbook is 540 and unfortunately there is no explanation given.
Is it just a typo or am I wrong and if so, **what is the correct way to solve such a problem**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct.  We can confirm this by subtracting the number of ways we can form teams where the two specified people are on the same team from the total number of ways we can divide the twelve people into teams of seven and five.

There are $\binom{12}{7}$ ways to select a team of seven people and a team of five people from the twelve available people since choosing which seven people are on the larger team automatically determines who will be on the smaller team.  The number of seven member teams that contain the two specific people is $\binom{10}{5}$ since we must choose which five of the other ten people are on their team.  The number of five member teams that contain the two specific people is $\binom{10}{3}$ since we must choose which three of the other ten people are on their team.  Hence, the number of permissible teams is 
$$\binom{12}{7} - \binom{10}{5} - \binom{10}{3} = 2\binom{10}{6}$$